# Shape error when using PolynomialFeatures

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

## The Issue

To begin with I'm pretty new to machine learning. I have decided to test up some of the things that I have learned on some financial datam my machine learning model looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/Documents/Trading.csv")
poly_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False)
linear_reg = LinearRegression(fit_intercept = True)

X = df_copy[["open","volume", "base volume", "RSI_14"]]
X_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(X)[1]


y = df_copy[["high"]]

linear_reg.fit(X_poly, y)

x = linear_reg.predict([[1.905E-05, 18637.07503453,0.35522205,  69.95820948552947]])
print(x)
```

all works great until the moment I try to implement `PolynomialFeatures` which brings to be the following error:

```
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

---

## Attempts to solve the issue:

**Atempt 1**

I've tried adding .values to `X` but the same error still comes up:

```
X_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(X.values)[1]
```

**Atempt 2**

I tried solving this problem by adding `reshape(-1, 1)` at the end of `X_poly`:

```
 X_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(X)[1].reshape(-1, 1)
```

but it just replaces the previous error with this one:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [14, 5696]
```

*Thank you very much in advance for your help.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wants you to transform your input. Try using `X_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(X.values.reshape(1,-1))[1]`

Comment: Oh my, Thank you very much it worked!!! I've just ran the code (about 5 minutes ago and it is still running, do you know why is that?)

Comment: The `PolynomialFeatures` transforms your data exponentially, so depending on the dimensions of your data set, so will your run time.